# Как удалить класс у всех элементов через refs

Tags: vue.js

У каждого блока есть кнопка при нажатии на которую добавляеться этому блоку класс sticky, когда я нажимаю на кнопку с другого блока я хочу полностью удалить у всех блоков класс sticky. Я делаю через ref чтобы добавить класс но проблема что когда я хочу удалить у всех элементов ничего не происходит в чём может быть проблема?

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index" :ref="`block-${index}`">
 <button @click="removeClass(index)>click</button>
</div>

methods: {
 removeClass(index) {
   this.items.forEach((item, ind) => {
      this.$refs[`block-${ind}`].classList.remove('sticky');
   });
   this.$refs[`block-${index}`][0].classList.add('sticky');
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял ту задачу, которыю Вы решаете, то у Вас не правильный подход к ее решению.
Ниже пример изменения класса элемента по клику

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      activeIndex: 0,
    }
  },
});
```

```css
#app {
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.block {
  height: 40px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.block.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.0"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="index in 5" class="block" :class="{active: activeIndex === index}" :key="index" @click="activeIndex = index">Click</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Я свою задачу упростил просто, на самом деле мне через ref нужно я так думаю там сделать. Я не пойму почему мой пример не работает